# "Unable to interpret path (null)" from instruments when trying to run calabash-ios test against Xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, instruments, calabash-ios

I have a new machine that is a clean setup of Ruby, Cucumber, and Calabash-IOS.

When I try to run cucumber from Terminal I get an error popup from instruments that says

"Unable to interpret path (null)" and the simulator never launches

I tried changing the APP_BUNDLE_PATH and I tried commenting out the APP_BUNDLE_PATH, neither worked.

This is a compiled .app file that was built using Xamarin Studio. I am assuming that instruments is having some problem with this .app file for some reason when it is trying to launch it? This same setup works fine on other machines so it must be an environmental 
problem.

Is there a way to get a better output log from cucumber or calabash (or instruments) so I can figure what exactly is throwing this error? Or does anyone have any ideas of what I can try to get calabash to launch my .app correctly in the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might stumble over this in the future.

In my case the issue was caused by an invalid .app package. I still don't know what was wrong with the specific package itself but something inside the .app must have been invalid causing the error. I recompiled my application and replaced the .app file that was being loaded but calabash and the problem went away.

a more informative error message would have been nice (something like, corrupt .app package detected) but oh well.

Hope it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: > instruments that says "Unable to interpret path (null)" and the simulator never launches - Was this a UI alert on your host machine?  Put another way, did MacOS pop this alert dialog?  If so, we can't control that.  Can you update your question with what appeared on the command line?

Comment: This was so long ago I don't have the exact command line spew. But it wasn't a macOS alert. It was spit out in the command line when running calabash. It was from inside calabash near as I can remember.